# Creating element with text at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a paragraph element with some text, but I think I'm appending the text before the paragraph element is added to the DOM. How can I fix this?

```
function myFn() {
  var paragraph = document.createElement("P");
  var text = document.createTextNode("This is some paragraph text.");

  paragraph.className = "heading";
  paragraph.style.width = "100vw";
  paragraph.style.background = "blue";
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(paragraph);
  document.getElementById("heading").appendChild(text);
}
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/XdGRXN

Thanks!

Comment: I have your code appending content. http://codepen.io/xequence/pen/ZWPKOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: [See DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1b3socko/)

```
function myFn() {  
  var paragraph = document.createElement("P");
  var text = document.createTextNode("This is some paragraph text.");

  paragraph.id = "heading";

  paragraph.style.width = "100vw";
  paragraph.style.background = "blue";
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(paragraph);
  document.getElementById("heading").appendChild(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function myFn() {
  var paragraph = document.createElement("P");
  var text = document.createTextNode("This is some paragraph text.");

  paragraph.style.width = "100vw";
  paragraph.style.background = "blue";
  paragraph.appendChild(text); 
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(paragraph);      
}
```

Comment: I like this because I append the text by referencing the paragraph's variable name, not element ID/class, but I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code to help append an element to your dom.

http://codepen.io/xequence/pen/ZWPKOW

```
    function myFn() {
  var paragraph = document.createElement("P");
  var text = document.createTextNode("This is some paragraph text.");

  paragraph.appendChild(text);

  paragraph.className = "heading";
  paragraph.style.width = "100vw";
  paragraph.style.background = "blue";
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("container");
  document.body.insertBefore(paragraph, currentDiv);
}
```